# GWT: Efficient loading of dynamic images

Tags: gwt

- I am creating a GWT application which displays a table of information.

  - Every row of the table corresponds to a data object.
  - In each row of the table, there is an image which must be **dynamically** generated (the image is a fairly simple function of the object associated with the row.)
  - To reiterate, it is **not** acceptable to pre-generate a universe of static images which covers everything needed by the table. The set of needed images is **unbounded**.

It would be easy to generate any one image within, say, a Canvas widget, **but**:

- I would prefer to use a CellTable, as there might be hundreds of rows to display.
- CellTable doesn't easily allow widgets like Canvas to be used within a cell.
- Anyways, drawing on 100's of Canvas's on the client side seems expensive.

I am wondering if there is an established efficient pattern for this scenario? I am thinking of the following (but I am not sure if it is feasible -- see below):

- Whenever the CellTable is updated, the client makes an RPC call -- e.g. "**getDynamicImageBundle(List<MyDataObject> objects)**",
- The return value for getDynamicImageBundle() should be a single composite image from which each component image can be easily extracted.
- The extracted images are used to populate the dynamic image column of the CellTable.

My questions are the following:

- The first question is "is this fundamentally impossible": i.e., if the job of a Cell in a CellTable is to generate HTML, and a dynamically generated image is a chunk of binary data that has nothing to do with any URL in particular, does that mean I simply can't use a CellTable here?
- More generally, am I going to have to "hack" GWT to associate these dynamic images with some made-up URL in order to get anything to work here? Or else use Canvas?
- If my high-level plan of action above (involving the RPC call) is in fact feasible, does anyone have pointers to GWT classes that will be of assistance here? It seems like components like ImageResource are built around a static-set-of-images scenario.

Comment: Generally you can use base64 encoded binary images in img tags. The specifics of CellTable is that you will have to redraw on image change (specific row or whole table). Could you also describe your scenario from other side just step-by-step how do you need the data to be populated on the CellTable

Comment: Thanks; I'll try using base64 encoded URI's and see if it works.